# Criteria to set to fetch a value from parent form in Query Design View in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a parent and child forms in MS Access. Each table in my DB have GUIDs as PK. In the child form, i have a custom dropdown control with custom SQL query as a Row Source. The query should show me the records that are relevant to the parent only so that they can be associated as child records. To filter, i set a criteria in the SQL query on the relevant field CASE_ID with expression **Forms![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID]** where ROW_ID is a GUID PK column in the parent S_CASE.

The problem starts here.

**NO RECORDS ARE BEING SHOWN IN THE DROPDOWN CONTROL OF THE CHILD FORM.**

To investgate why no records are being shown, while the actual parent and child forms are opened and minimized, i prepared a simple independent query **SELECT [Forms]![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID] FROM S_CASE_CON;** and executed it. The query is returning the records with ROW_ID value of parent as seen in the UI and as expected. As the Expression [Forms]![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID] is observed to be fetching the value, i shifted the expression to criteria and made the query as **SELECT ROW_ID FROM S_CASE_CON WHERE CASE_ID = [Forms]![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID];**. In this case, to my surprise, the query is not returning any records. No clue why! I also tried other expressions like **StringFromGUID(Forms![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID])** and **Mid(StringFromGUID(Forms![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID]),8,36)**, **StringFromGUID([Parent]![ROW_ID])** and none worked for me.

More Research:
In immediate window, the expression
**?[Forms]![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID]** is giving the result as ?????? as it is GUID field.
**?StringFromGUID(Forms![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID])** is giving the result {guid {41E6F272-3C69-455E-8B06-15C08166456B}} which is also as expected.
**?Mid(StringFromGUID(Forms![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID]),8,36)** is giving the result 41E6F272-3C69-455E-8B06-15C08166456B

For same and unknown reason as detailed above, the Row Source query of dropdown control is not showing any records for using the expression [Forms]![Parent Form Name]![ROW_ID] as criteria. Can anybody help me on the problem with the criteria and how to show relevant records by refrring to the value of a control in parent form??

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Don't filter the subform recordsource; set the `MasterLinkFields` and `ChildLinkFields` properties of the subform control.

Comment: Subform loads before parent form so info on parent form is not available when child form loads. As Gustav already advised, use Master/Child Links properties of subform container control to synchronize form/subform arrangement.